# Communication between two private networks in Google Cloud networking

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, openstack-neutron

I have two networks Pvt-net1 and Pvt-net2 as custom subnet networks in Google cloud networking.
Each of network is having one subnet.

Pvt-net1 is having subnet pvt-net1subnet1 192.168.1.0/16 in region us-central1.
Pvt-net2 is having subnet pvt-net2subnet1 192.168.2.0/16 in region us-central1.

I don't want to have both subnets under same network. I am trying to map Openstack networking to Google Cloud networking.

How can form communication between Pvt-net1 and Pvt-net2 with private IP's?
Can I use routes and firewalls here? What could be better way to setup routing between to different networks in same Google project?

**Edit:**
I am working on Openstack project which maps Openstack network resources to Google Cloud networking Resources.
I am mapping Openstack network, subnet to Google cloud network, subnet. Now as we create route between networks in Openstack, I want to map same action to GCE.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have not elaborated on your use case, but maybe you can create one network with 2 [sub-networks]
(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/subnetworks).

2) If you need 2 separate networks, you can use [network peering](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/peering-networks) or create two [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview) (one per network),which are connected to each other.

Answer (score 0):

VPC networks can be connected to other VPC networks in different projects or organizations by using [VPC Network Peering.](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering)